# <select multiple> for only 4 objects

Tags: html, selection

Is this possible? to only allow you to select 4 objects, with out using javascript or php (or what ever serrver side language your using)?

if I had something like:

```
<select multiple>
    <option>cat</option>
    <option>hat</option>
    <option>sat</option>
    <option>fat</option>
    <option>brat</option>
</select>
```

can I put a limit on it and say only 4 of those can be selected? is this where `size=4` would come in handy?

this is **not** a duplicate

Comment: I can't think of any html code which does this without js or php.

Comment: what is the easiest way to do it with jquery? @user927258

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to enforce such a limit without the use of JavaScript. Something like this could work:

```
func = function(e) {
    e|e=window.event;
    var t = e.srcElement || e.target;
    if( !t.tagName) t = t.parentNode;
    if( t.tagName.toLowerCase() == "select" && t.hasAttribute("multiple") && t.hasAttribute("data-max")) {
        var o = t.options, l = o.length, i, m = +t.getAttribute("data-max");
        for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
            if( o[i].selected) {
                if(m>0) m--;
                else o[i].selected = false;
            }
        }
    }
};
if( document.body.addEventListener) document.body.addEventListener("change",func,false);
else document.body.attachEvent("onchange",func);
```

Then you can use this HTML:

```
<select multiple data-max="4">
```

---

Additionally, you should implement server-side validation. Assuming this HTML:

```
<select multiple name="test[]">
```

You could use this PHP:

```
$_POST['test'] = array_slice($_POST['test'],0,4); // adjust the 4 to whatever limit
```